# Retrieve a pdf/tiff from ftp server and send it to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, ftp, tiff

I am trying to retrieve multiple pdf/tiff file from a particular location in the FTP server, join them and send them to a jsp page to be displayed. So far, this is what i have done.

In the action class, 
a)i try to retrieve the file details in a bean called pdfbean, 
b)pass pdfbean to a method which makes an ftp connection and retrieves the file from the server
c)convert it into a byte[] and return it to be added to a document.

Now this document is stored in C:\ which is not what i want. I want to send it to a jsp page. As of now, i dont know how to send it.

```
            ArrayList<PdfBean> list = msgDH.getFileDtls(hawbString);
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter write = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,
                    new FileOutputStream("c://Image.pdf"));
            write.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_5);
            doc.open();

            for (PdfBean pdfBean : list)
            {
                byte[] Image2 = getfile(pdfBean);
                Image img = Image.getInstance(Image2);
                doc.add(img);
                doc.newPage();
            }
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("Done saving");
```

Below is the getfile() methood

```
private byte[] getfile(PdfBean pdfBean)
{

    byte[] result = null;
    boolean test = false;
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    DataSourceReader dsr = new DataSourceReader();
    dsr.getFtpLinks();
    String ftppassword = dsr.getFtppassword();
    String ftpserver = dsr.getFtpserver();
    String ftpusername = dsr.getFtpusername();
    System.out.println("no" + ftpserver + ftpusername + ftppassword);
    try
    {
        ftp.connect(ftpserver);
    } catch (SocketException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        boolean login = ftp.login(ftpusername, ftppassword);
    } catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        int reply;
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        {
            ftp.disconnect();
            System.out.println("FTP server refused connection.");
        } else
        {

            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles(pdfBean.getFileLocation());

            String fN = "";
            int i = 0;
          //tiff and pdf files reside in different folders. 
            if (pdfBean.getFileLocation().equals("/hold/TIF"))
            {
                String F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF", ".TIF");
                for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                {
                    if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                    {
                        fN = pdfBean.getFileLocation().concat("/")
                                .concat(F);
                        i = 1;
                    }

                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF", ".TIFF");
                    for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                    {
                        if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                        {
                            fN = pdfBean.getFileLocation().concat("/")
                                    .concat(F);
                            i = 1;
                        }

                    }
                }

            } else
            {
                fN = pdfBean.getFileLocation().concat("/")
                        .concat(pdfBean.getFileName());
            }
            InputStream in = ftp.retrieveFileStream(fN);
            BufferedInputStream inbf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);// new byte[1024];
            result = buffer;
            /*
             * int readCount;
             * 
             * int lenght = 0;
             * 
             * while( (readCount = inbf.read(buffer)) > 0) { int preLength =
             * lenght; lenght += readCount; byte temp[] = new
             * byte[result.length]; result = new byte[lenght];
             * System.arraycopy(temp,0,result,0,temp.length);
             * System.arraycopy(buffer,0,result,preLength,readCount); }
             */

        }

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception ----->" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (bis != null)
            {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (is != null)
            {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            ftp.logout();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

I get a java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException Where am i going wrong. And do you foresee any problems in adding a tif and pdf as images to the same document. And finally, once i have the file ready, how do i send it to a JSP page ?

Comment: 1. what line give exception? 2. What do you mean by "send to jsp"?

Comment: I got it at byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(in); WHen i say send to JSP, I want the merged file to be displayed in a JSP. Im making a temporary file in C drive only for testing.

Comment: 1. try to use `byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(inbf);` 2. I still cannot understand how jsp can display image, do you mean `IMG` tag?

Comment: i will add all the files to a document.. and then i dont know what to do. still figuring out.

Comment: I see. you cannot display pdf as image, you can only provide user with generated pdf file, this file can be either on server's disk or in db, so you can either put generated pdf into some web accessible folder or output it via jsp like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133920/is-it-possible-to-download-a-binary-file-from-jsp

Answer (score 0):

```
for (PdfBean pdfBean : list)
            {
                if(!pdfBean.getFileName().isEmpty()&&!pdfBean.getFileLocation().isEmpty()){


                msgDH.InsertUserHistDtls(pdfBean.getHawb(), userId, pdfBean.getCustomer(), pdfBean.getFileName(), pdfBean.getProduct(), pdfBean.getDocType(), "Print");
                msgDH.InsertLogDtls(pdfBean.getFileName(), pdfBean.getProduct(), pdfBean.getCustomer(), userId);

                FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
                int tiffPages = 0;
                try
                {
                    ftp.connect(ftpserver);
                } catch (SocketException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try
                {
                    boolean login = ftp.login(ftpusername, ftppassword);
                } catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                int reply;
                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
                {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    System.out.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                } else
                {
                    // ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
                    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(pdfBean.getFileLocation());
                    /* FTPFile[] */
                    ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();
                    /* FTPFile[] */// ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();
                    // ftp.completePendingCommand();
                }

                String fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation() + "/"
                        + pdfBean.getFileName();
                if ("/interface/oracle/dds/generic/hold/TIF"
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(pdfBean.getFileLocation()))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    String F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF",
                            ".TIF");
                    // FTPFile[] ftpFiles =
                    // ftp.listFiles(pdfBean.getFileLocation());
                    for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                    {
                        if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                        {
                            fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation()
                                    .concat("/").concat(F);
                            i = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        F = pdfBean.getFileName().replaceAll(".PDF",
                                ".TIFF");
                        for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
                        {
                            if (ftpFile.getName().equals(F))
                            {
                                fileName = pdfBean.getFileLocation()
                                        .concat("/").concat(F);
                                i = 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    int Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    //
                    // System.out.println(Repcode);
                    /* if(fileName.endsWith(".TIF")) */

                    InputStream is = (InputStream) ftp.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
                    Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    System.out.println(Repcode);
                    // ftp.completePendingCommand();
                    Repcode = ftp.getReplyCode();
                    System.out.println(Repcode);
                    ra1 = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(is);
                    tiffPages = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(ra1);
                    System.out.println("No of pages in image is : "
                            + tiffPages);
                    for (int a = 1; a <= tiffPages; a++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Image img = TiffImage.getTiffImage(ra1, a);
                            if (img != null)
                            {
                                if (img.getScaledWidth() > 500
                                        || img.getScaledHeight() > 700)
                                {
                                    img.scaleToFit(800, 800);
                                }
                                doc.setPageSize(new Rectangle(img
                                        .getScaledWidth(), img
                                        .getScaledHeight()));
                                img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                                cb.addImage(img);
                                // doc.
                                doc.newPage();
                                // ++pages;
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Exception " + " page "
                                    + (a + 1) + " " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    is.close();
                    ra1.close();

                }
                else{

                    InputStream pdf = ftp.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
                    if(pdf != null) {
                        PdfReader pdfRea = new PdfReader(pdf);
                        readers.add(pdfRea);
                        totalPages += pdfRea.getNumberOfPages();   
                    }


                    /*totalPages += pdfRea.getNumberOfPages();


                    PdfImportedPage page;
                    int currentPageNumber = 0;
                    int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                    Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                            BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                   // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
                   while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                       PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                       // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                       while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                           doc.newPage();
                           pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                           currentPageNumber++;
                           page = write.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                           cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                           // Code for pagination.
                           cb.beginText();
                           cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                           cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                   + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520, 5, 0);
                           cb.endText();
                       }
                       pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                   }*/
                }

                ftp.logout();
                ftp.disconnect();
                ftp = null;
            }}



            PdfImportedPage page;
            int currentPageNumber = 0;
            int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                    BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
           // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
           while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
               PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

               // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
               while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                   doc.newPage();
                   pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                   currentPageNumber++;
                   page = write.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                   cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                   // Code for pagination.
                   cb.beginText();
                   cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                   cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                           + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520, 5, 0);
                   cb.endText();
               }
               pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
           }
        }
        doc.close();
        write.flush();
        write.close();
        System.out.println("done printing");

    }


    FileInputStream fiss = new FileInputStream(temp);  
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fiss);
    response.reset();
```